# Make visual studio understand the return type of a web service is the same as an existing type

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I've been googling for ages now, but cannot find an answer to the problem I'm facing. Here's the situation:

I have a .Net web service (not a wcf service, but an old fashioned web service), that has a web method in it returning, say, an object of type X.

Now when i create a service reference to this web service from a different .Net project, visual studio will generate a proxy class (in the reference.vb), and the return type of the web method in this class is that proxy class (say, type Y) instead of type X.

The thing is, type X is a type that is declared in an external reference that exists in both ends of the web method. Is there ANY way (the service itself should stay a web service, but I don't care if the reference is a "service reference" or a "web reference") i can make visual studio understand that there is no need to create a proxy class and it can use the existing type for the return type of the method?

I know that service references can automatically map types (you can set these settings when creating the service reference). However, this only seems to work when creating a service reference to a wcf service, not to a normal .net web service

Update:

It seems i need to somehow make visual studio match the namespaces of the types. John Saunders hinted me to the xmltype attribute i can use to specify the full namespace of the type. I will try if this works.

I also thought about how visual studio matches the classes. It seems there is no info about namespaces in the wsdl of the web service anywhere (assuming studio uses the wsdl as input for generating the reference) so how can studio match the types?

Update2:
I've tried to use the xmltype to map the namespace. I wasn't sure what namespace to use (the uri kind of the actual ClrNamespace) so i tried both. Using the  uri namespace I was able to create a namespace mapping in the svcmap, but this caused the code in the reference.vb file to be generated inside an extra namespace instead of making VS want to map the type. Any new idea's? Can this really be this hard?

Comment: WCF _is_ normal .net web services. ASMX services are the old, legacy technology.

Comment: Did you try, in the "Add Service Reference" dialog, specifying "Reuse types"? Is the assembly containing the shared types referenced by your client application? You may still have issues because of namespaces.

Comment: Thats just a technicality, the original question remains

Comment: Both the server and the client reference the same assembly, containing the required type. The reuse types is enabled by default, but it doesn't seem to understand the link between the types. I'm trying to make the system understand the two types are the same. I haven't done anything with namespaces though...

Comment: With my googling I encountered some mentioning of namespace mapping, but I couldn't make heads or tails about it and didn't seem to apply to my situation. The web service is indeed in a different namespace than the return type of the method

Comment: I never thought about it before now, but how does "Add Service Reference" match the types? It's just reading the metadata - it doesn't actually know there's a .NET service on the other end of the "Add Service Reference" URL. It must match between the metadata and the types in the referenced assemblies. It must be matching on name and namespace. Try using `[XmlType]` etc. on the referenced classes to specify the namespace explicitly.

Comment: The information on namespaces (XML namespaces) _is_ in the WSDL, specifically in the XML Schemas under `<wsdl:types>`. I meant that VS sees the namespaces in the WSDL, and must determine the namespaces of the types in the referenced assemblies. Specify `[XmlType]` to help it do so, since the service used XmlSerializer and the types in the assembly may not be decorated with `[XmlType]` and such.

Comment: Ok, I'm probably an idiot, but I'm not getting it. What attributes with what value should i be adding to what class? I've tried adding the xmltype to class X (the type it should map to), this does include extra info in the wsdl, but it doesn't make visual studio want to map the types

Comment: ow, what i seemed to do is (after creating a namespacemapping in the svcmap) is create the target namespace in the reference.vb, instead of mapping the types, so now all the proxy data is an extra namespace

Comment: I'll try to get some time to play with this, but you may want to create yourself a dummy ASMX service and a dummy WCF service and check to see how "Add Service Reference" behaves differently between the two. Then do the usual "morph" of one into the other until the behavior changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply doesn't seem possible to do this. The short answer: use a wcf service reference and create a shared library with the types used in the service and reference them in both the service and the application with the reference